# does anybody know why the pagina reloads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Does anybody know why the page reloads when i click on the bold button?

Because when i want to make a text bold and click on the button, the page reloads automatically

```js
 $('#bold_btn').on('click', function () {
            document.execCommand('bold');
            var text = document.getElementById('textarea').innerHTML;
            $('#textarea-show').html(text);
        });
        $('#italic_btn').on('click', function () {
            document.execCommand('italic');
            var text = document.getElementById('textarea').innerHTML;
            $('#textarea-show').html(text);
        });

        console.log()

        $('.saveBtn').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            let data = $( "div#textarea" ).html();
            $('textarea#answerstextarea').html(data);
           $('#question-create-form').submit();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <button id='bold_btn' class="btn btn-outline-secondary"><b>B</b></button>
                <button id='italic_btn'class="btn btn-outline-secondary"><i>I</i></button>
                <div contenteditable="true" id="textarea" name="answers" class="form-control">{{ old('answers',$task->description) }}</div>

<textarea name="answers" id="answerstextarea"></textarea>
```

Comment: I think we need a bit more information / code in order to tell you what the problem is

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take your time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and edit your question to follow those guidelines. Help us help you. At this very moment, it is near impossible to help you in an accurate way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the type on the button to 'button'. It may be defaulting to 'submit'

```
<button id='bold_btn' type='button' class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
  <b>B</b>
</button>
```